# Getting data from Json string into javascript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a asp.net webservice, which is pulling some data from my database, and outputting this JSON string:

```
{
"NumberOfCustomers": 15,
"Customer": [
    {
        "CusID": "1",
        "FirstName": "Ina",
        "LastName": "Williamson"
    },
    {
        "CusID": "2",
        "FirstName": "Hyacinth",
        "LastName": "Brady"
    },
    {
        "CusID": "3",
        "FirstName": "Coby",
        "LastName": "Shannon"
    }
]
```

> }

I then try to use jQuery to display each of the customers, but i can't get it working. The purpose for this, is to use the data as a suggestion to a search field, that updates for each character written.

```
function FinalTest() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:12724/VetWebservice.asmx/GetCustomer",
                data: "{}", 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function (data) {
glb = data; //variable for inspecting in Chrome
                    $("#testdiv3").html(data.d.NumberOfCustomers);
                    $.each(data.d.Customer, function () {
                        $("#testdiv3").append(this.CusID + ", ");
                    });


                }
            });
        };
```

Giving me this error:

> TypeError: a is undefined
>
> jquery.min.js (linje 2)

It has something to do with the pointing to specific parts of the JSON array. But i can't figure out why it isnt working.

The "d" of the data.d path, is because asp.net webservice for some unknown reason wraps it in a d key property.

> data.d.NumberOfCustomers

Its also possible to change the JSON string that i create from my webservice, if that would help solving it somehow. But my JSON syntax validates on [jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com)

Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

---

EDIT: added glb object for inspecting + the result of it from Chrome

Inspecting the "glb" gives this result:

```
Object {d: "{"NumberOfCustomers":15, "Customer":[{"CusID":"1",…D":"15","FirstName":"Adele","LastName":"Woods"}]}"}
```

Which looks like what i expect; wrapped in the "d" property cause of the asp.net webservice.

When running my jquery snippet in Chrome, im also getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery.min.js:2
n.extend.each jquery.min.js:2 
FinalTest.$.ajax.success Customers.aspx:226 
j jquery.min.js:2 
k.fireWith jquery.min.js:2 
x jquery.min.js:4 
b jquery.min.js:4
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `console.log()` to print out your data to make sure you're receiving what you think you are?  Also, why are you doing `data.d.NumberOfCustomers` versus `data.NumberOfCustomers`?  Also, you may want to check out JQuery's `parseJSON()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
data.NumberOfCustomers
```

instead of

```
data.d.NumberOfCustomers
```

and

```
data.Customer
```

instead of

```
data.d.Customer
```

.

Comment: asp.net webmethod puts the result in property name d. dont know why. just that it does that.

Comment: Indeed it does, and that only contributes to my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

i've tried the following code in the chrome console and it worked:

```
data = {
"NumberOfCustomers": 15,
"Customer": [
    {
        "CusID": "1",
        "FirstName": "Ina",
        "LastName": "Williamson"
    },
    {
        "CusID": "2",
        "FirstName": "Hyacinth",
        "LastName": "Brady"
    },
    {
        "CusID": "3",
        "FirstName": "Coby",
        "LastName": "Shannon"
    }
]}


$.each(data.Customer,function() { alert(this.CusID); });
```

I remember asp.net webmethod put the result in property d but perhaps its structure a bit different then what you expect. 
I would suggest to add an assignment to global var the value returned from service and investigate it using the console.

in the ajax success add line at the head of the function as follows:

```
glb = data; //glb will be a global scope var which you can investigate on console upon end of execution.
```

than on chrome console just type glb and press enter. then you would be able to investigate the object and try the each function without doing the ajax call.

Comment: inspecting the "glb" gives this result:
Object {d: "{"NumberOfCustomers":15, "Customer":[{"CusID":"1",…D":"15","FirstName":"Adele","LastName":"Woods"}]}"}
Which looks like what i expect; wrapped in the "d" property cause of the asp.net webservice.
When running my jquery snippet in Chrome, im also getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery.min.js:2
n.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
FinalTest.$.ajax.success Customers.aspx:226
j jquery.min.js:2
k.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
x jquery.min.js:4
b jquery.min.js:4

Any idea why that is?

Comment: Added your suggestion to the question instead. My above comment was unreadable.
Its throwing this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined "